# PyOpenCV will not build on Raspbian with Python2.7

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install PyOpenCV on my Raspberry Pi so that I can use the webcam capture functionality of it. Unfortunately, I seem to be having quite a bit of difficulty with this as I can't get the darn thing to build for me.

I've got all of the prerequisites as defined by various tutorials I've read, but when I use CMake-GUI to try to configure the build, I get thrown this error

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97           (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:186 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)
```

I've tried manually adding a PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS variable to cmake with the value of "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" and '/usr/lib/python2.7", both of which fail with the same error.

I'm quite inexperienced when it comes to building with CMake, so I'm probably doing something stupid and easy to fix.

Alternatively; I am open to suggestions for lighter and faster methods of accessing webcam through python on linux, as I understand OpenCV is quite a large module to use for just this one small function. I do only have 700mHz at my disposal here.

Comment: Do you have the python `devel` package installed?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```